# More than one graphic in Graphics command

Tags: graphics

another question regarding plotting. I'm sorry, but somehow it is superhard for me to use these. I have a Graphics plot and I want to add a Point to it. A circle is already working. But everything becomes red when I do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Circle[{10*t, 10}, radius], Point[{0, 0}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 200}, {-20, 200}}], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

What am I doint wrong? Isn't it possible to add more than one graphic in Graphics?

Comment: You need to enclose all the stuff you want to show in curly brackets: `Graphics[{x,y,z,...},opts]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. Please compare:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[{10*t, 10}, 10], PointSize@0.02, Point[{0, 0}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 200}, {-20, 200}}], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]